# JMeter master slave setup on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I want to setup a 3 node cluster for JMeter on AWS EC2 instances.

I am not able to find any reference. Can anybody guide it

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 instances don't differ from any other computers so you can follow instructions from [Remote Testing](http://Remote%20Testing) guide.

Just make sure to unblock the following ports in [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

- 1099
- the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
- the port(s) you define as `client.rmi.localport`

References:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

You may also find [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) useful

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this AWS CDK based framework for running Jmeter tests in distributed mode on AWS (FARGATE/ECS using Jmeter Docker containers)

https://github.com/pranavkakde/aws-cdk-load-test-jmeter